# passing exception from child function try/catch to parent-caller function try/catch

Tags: php, laravel

i have function `a` with try/catch block , it's calling function `b` which has it's own try/catch block ... when exception happens in function `b` i want to activate catch block in the function `a` so i can log my errors from single line

```
function a(){

        try
        {
            doo stuff 
            $this->b();
             
        }
        catch (\Exception $exception)
        {
            //ErrorLog | line / message / file 
        }

}


function b(){

    DB::beginTransaction();
    try 
    {
       db insert 
       DB::commit();
    }
    catch (\Exception $exception)
    {
         DB::rollBack();
    }

}
```

my question is how can i pass exception from function `b` to catch block in function `a`  ? i can throw new exception from catch block

```
catch (\Exception $exception)
{
     DB::rollBack();
     throw new Exception("something wrong in function b");
}
```

but it's not going to contain error data

Comment: why not throw $exception? Or create your own exception class with the original  contain error data as a prop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just re-throw the exception...

```php
catch (\Exception $exception)
{
    DB::rollBack();
    throw $exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options which you can do it with.

- Re-throwing the same exception and cathing in the parent
- Throwing the custom exception and cathing in the parent

##### Rethrowing the same exeption

You can re-throw an exception using the throw keyword without any arguments inside the catch block of method `b`. This will re-throw the same exception that was caught in the catch block on method `b`, allowing you to catch it again in an outer try/catch block of method `a`.

Here is how you can do it:

```php
function a() {
  try {
    b();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    // Log the error from function b here
    echo "Error in function b: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}

function b() {
  try {
    // Some code that may throw an exception
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    // Rollback
    // Add additional information to the exception and re-throw it
    throw new Exception("Error in function b: " . $e->getMessage(), 0, $e);
  }
}
```

In this example, we create a new Exception object with a custom message and pass the original exception as the third argument to the constructor. This preserves the original exception's type and stacktrace, while adding additional information to the message.

##### Throwing a custom exception

Here is how you can do it:

```php
// Create new exception
class MyException extends Exception {}

function a() {
  try {
    b();
  }catch(MyException $e){
   echo "Custom Exception thrown from function b: " . $e->getMessage();
 }catch (Exception $e) {
    // All other errors
    echo "Error " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}

function b() {
  try {
    // Some code that may throw an exception
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    // Rollback
    throw new MyException("Error in function b");
  }
}
```